# Assign, Save and Load a Sequence of Objects to a Sequence of Variables in R

Tags: r

I would like to assign a sequence of results to a sequence of variables and then save these variables in a sequence of .Rdata files. I want to do this in order to use sapply to load all the .Rdata files once I'll need them.
To illustrate my problem, I wrote a simple function *save.try1*, and ran it 5 times.

```
save.try1 = function(x){

M = matrix(c(x,x+1,x+2,x+3), ncol=2, nrow = 2)

filename = paste('/Volumes/GIORDANO 3/MTS/MTS - essai/matrice', x, '.Rdata', sep='')

save(M, file =filename) 

}

sapply(1:5, save.try1)
```

I now have 5 .Rdata files named *matrice1.Rdata, ... , matrice5.Rdata* in my folder *MTS - essai*.

Now, when I load the files in R, I obtain:

```
> matrices.chargees = sapply(1:5, function(x) load(file = paste('/Volumes/GIORDANO 3/MTS/MTS - essai/matrice', x, '.Rdata', sep='')))
> matrices.chargees
[1] "M" "M" "M" "M" "M"
```

And I can't open any of the *M* matrices:

```
> matrices.chargees[[2]]
[1] "M"
> matrices.chargees[2]
[1] "M"
> matrices.chargees$M
Error in matrices.chargees$M : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

First, I want to have different names for each matrix. I read the following post:

[how to assign a sequence of computations to a sequence of variables in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159881/how-to-assign-a-sequence-of-computations-to-a-sequence-of-variables-in-r)

I tried to change my code to:

```
save.try1 = function(x){

M = matrix(c(x,x+1,x+2,x+3), ncol=2, nrow = 2)

assign(paste('M', x, sep =''), M)

filename = paste('/Volumes/GIORDANO 3/MTS/MTS - essai/matrice', x, '.Rdata', sep='')

save(paste('M', x, sep =''), file =filename) 

}
```

But I obtain the following error:

```
> sapply(1:5, save.try1)
Error in save(paste("M", x, sep = ""), file = filename) : 
  object ‘paste("M", x, sep = "")’ not found
```

My questions are therefore the following:

1- how do I modify my code to have a different name for each matrix?
2- Will this allow me to access the content of each matrix? If not, how do I access it?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `assign`. Just make a list and assign using `[[`: `mylist <- list(); mylist[[myname]] <- mything_for_myname`. I doubt that you need to save inside a function; just save `mylist` after you have populated it or save in a loop if you must. I guess the important thing to know is that you can put either a number *or a name* inside `[[]]`

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use = in your assignments unless you know *exactly* what you are doing.

Here is a working version of your function. You need to tell `save` that your argument is a variable name **as a string** not a symbol:

```
save.try1 <- function(x){
    M <- matrix(c(x,x+1,x+2,x+3), ncol=2, nrow = 2)

    foo <- paste('M', x, sep ='')

    assign(foo, M)

    filename <- paste('ENTER_YOUR_PATH_HERE', x, '.Rdata', sep='')

    save(list=foo, file=filename) 
}
```

Having said that, I really doubt using a functional instead of a for loop here is good style. Functionals are supposed to return a structure of values not a list of NULLs as this sapply call will. Love your for loops even in R, they exist for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a tiny error in your load script.  Load returns *A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly.* (see `?load`).

So with small fixes it will load the matrices as expected:

```
matrices.chargees = sapply(1:5, function(x) {
  name <- load(file = paste('matrice', x, '.Rdata', sep=''))
  out <- list(get(text=name))
  names(out) <- name
  out })
```